# Convert this stored procedure from T-SQL to MySQL syntax?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, t-sql

I see this error in execution I write it in SQL Server and want to convert it to mysql

> 1 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that
>   corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'db_cursor    FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO CityName,CountryName
>   WHILE @@FETC' at line 11 C:\Users\Dt4IT\Desktop\SQL.sql 2 1

```
delimiter #
Create Procedure ss()

begin
DECLARE CityName VARCHAR(100); -- filename for backup  
DECLARE CountryName VARCHAR(100);

DECLARE db_cursor CURSOR FOR  
SELECT CityName,(Select Country from d_country where CountryID = d_country.CountryID) 
FROM d_cities;

OPEN db_cursor   
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO CityName,CountryName 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0   
BEGIN 
    Insert into ip_relations
    Select city_name,country_name,ip_from,ip_to from ip2location_db11 where 
    city_name = CityName and country_name = CountryName
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO CityName,CountryName 
END   

CLOSE db_cursor   
DEALLOCATE db_cursor
end#
  delimiter ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should use `@` as prefix for these local variables:

```
DECLARE @CityName VARCHAR(100), @CountryName VARCHAR(100);
```

...

```
FETCH NEXT FROM db_cursor INTO @CityName,@CountryName
```

...

Comment: Not only is your answer wrong, you're also mixing user defined variables (those with the @ in front of them) and locally defined variables, which doesn't work. And there's a huge difference between them.

Comment: my bad, read wrong, thought he wants to convert from mysql to sql server. there you have to use @local_variable.